# Need to get the minimum cell size of collection of rasters

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have the following model in ModelBuilder:

[image: Model]

Get Raster Properties looks like this . . .
[image: Get Raster Properties]
I need to find the minimum cell size value to use as output.  Any ideas on what tool I should use to replace Cell Statistics?
Thanks,
Renee

---

As I said above, the reason I need to get the minimum value of the cell size is because I need to create an empty output raster dataset that has compatible characteristics with the input rasters to be mosaicked together.  However, I have another model that could get me around the above situation with having to create an output raster ahead of time.  In the following model, I use "Mosaic to New Raster" rather than "Mosaic".  This should work out well, but the output comes out crazy looking.  Here is the model and the output . . .
[image: Mosaic To New Raster Model]

[image: Result of Mosaic To New Raster]

Comment: The screen shots in the original post got messed up for some reason, but I corrected them.  Hope this didn't cause any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get minimum cell size for collection of rasters:

1. Add the Calculate Value tool to your inner model (iterate selected rasters) after Collect Values.
2. Connect the Collect Values output as a precondition to Calculate Value.
3. Define a small function within Calculate Value **(Code Block)** as shown below.

   ```
   def minCellSize(rasters):
    rasterList = rasters.split(";")
    return min([arcpy.Describe(r).meanCellHeight for r in rasterList])
   ```
4. Type this in the expression
   **minCellSize("%Rasters%")**
5. Set **Double** as the data type
6. Set the output from Calculate Value as a model Parameter (**The output from Collect values remains a model parameter)**
7. Connect the Calculate Value output to the cell size variable of the Mosaic To New Raster tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a bit of **arcpy** you can implement the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000) function. As you iterate over your rasters simply use:

```
inRaster = 'C:\...\raster'
describeRaster = arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
cellSize = describeRaster.children[0].meanCellHeight # or .meanCellWidth
```

Now you can compare your `cellSize` variable to find the minimum.

**EDIT:**

You can get the minimum and maximum cell size of rasters in a mosaic dataset by using the [Calculate Size Ranges](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000008m000000) tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm looking for a geoprocessing tool that could take the collected values and get the minimum value.

Comment: Is the output of the entire model to be a single value (cell size)? If so, are you tied to using model builder? It seems like a more complex solution than necessary to get the minimum cell size.

Comment: I agree with you on that.  Actually I'm working on this as a sub-model (one of about 6 or 7) to work with a Main model.  I want to create a Main geoprocessing model that does the DTED mosaicking, slope generation and suitability. Then I would need to save it as a geoprocessing package.  I'm taking it one step at a time.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason I need to get the minimum value of the cell size is because I need to create an empty output raster dataset that has compatible characteristics with the input rasters to be mosaicked together. This is not the complete sub-model for this.  I will also do a "CreateRasterDataset" after obtaining the proper cell size.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I edited my answer to include the Calculate Size Ranges geoprocessing tool. Using this would alter your routine though - you would have to mosaic the rasters and then calculate the cell sizes, which you could then use to resample the final dataset. Perhaps someone else can offer a more suitable solution.

Comment: The "Mosaic" tool that I use in my other model requires an output raster to already exist that has the right properties.  If I end up using "Mosaic to New Raster" I would not need to do the above, but so far I've not been able to get that to work.  I'll describe that approach here. . .